# load div with images only when loaded

Tags: jquery, image, load

I want to load images only when they are loaded.

This is not working, since the class 'hidden' is removed before the images are loaded :

```
$(function(){
$('#nowplaying').load('nowplaying.php', function() {
    $('#images').removeClass('hidden');
}
)});
```

What could I do ?

EDIT : here's my code :

In index.php I have :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('#nowplaying').load('nowplaying.php');
});
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#nowplaying').load('nowplaying.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

In nowplaying.php I have this div:

```
echo "<div id="images">;
foreach ($jpg_files as $file) {
if (file_exists($cover_path."\\\\".$file) && $file!="f.jpg") {
$file = urlencode($file);
echo "<a href=\"getimage.php?img=".$file."\" target=\"_blank\">
<img src=\"getimage.php?img=".$file."&p=".$cover_path."\" /></a>";
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
}
echo "</div>;
```

I want to show the images of div id #images only when they are loaded (I don't want the user to see the image making in the browser).

How to do it?

Can someone send a simple example of waitForImages ?
It doesn't work at all for me.

EDIT 12-12-15 : 
This is working :

```
<img style="display:none;" src="big3.jpg">
<script type="text/javascript">
$('img').load(function(){
    $(this).css({'display':'block'})
});
</script>
```

But this is not working, why? :

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <img src="big3.jpg">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('div').load(function(){
    $(this).css({'display':'block'})
});
</script>
```

Still don't know why. But this is working if img has normal src  : 
Below the div :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div.images").hide();
$("div.images").find("img").load(function(){
$(this).closest("div.images").show();
});
});
</script>
```

NOW HERE'S MY BIG PROBLEM :
My images src is calling a script :

```
<img src=\"getimage.php?img=".$file."\" />";
```

How can I make it work with this?

Comment: Do you mean *I want to **show** images only when they are loaded*?

Comment: Yes Bram, I want to show images only when they are loaded

Comment: New edit, for something that works and don't.

Answer (score 1):

Does it solve your problem?

```
$('#images').load(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('img').load()` is unreliable and doesn't work cross browser.
I'd use something like waitForImages: https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Comment: I want to first load nowplaying.php inside my div #id nowplaying.

Comment: Then I want to see the images that are inside div #id images that is inside div #id nowplaying, only when they are loaded.

Comment: I recently used waitForImages on a site which ajaxed in all it's data and was based heavily on images and it worked really well.

What have you tried? Perhaps show us your code?

Comment: waitForImages should do what you are after, you need to be more specific about your problem

Comment: I would load you page using ajax then on success call waitforimages then in the call back remove the class of hidden off the images, you can remove it as each image is loaded or when all of them have loaded, depending on what you want

Comment: Maybe I'm not using waitForImages the right way. Here's what I do :

Comment: <script>
(function(e) etc.
$('#image').waitForImages(function() {
    // All descendant images have loaded, now slide up.
    $(this).slideUp();  
});
</script>

and in the body :
<img id="image" src="img.jpg" />

Comment: I say it's not working because I see the image loading in firefox.

Should the image appear 100% complete when it is loaded?  Or is it normal to see the image loading in firefox even if it's loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need my plugin - http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/BatchImagesLoad

Then you can do an operation after all images are loaded.